# Iterating a recursive split of defined depth

Tags: recursion, split, tree, iteration, depth

I have two vertices (a) and (b) and I want to recursively split them at their midpoints.

The pattern looks like this:

[image]

For this specific depth I can write it like this:

```
       a_b = self.abfn(   a,    b)

      ab_b = self.abfn( a_b,    b)
      a_ab = self.abfn(   a,  a_b)
    
     abb_b = self.abfn(ab_b,    b)
    ab_abb = self.abfn( a_b, ab_b)
     a_aab = self.abfn(   a, a_ab)
    aab_ab = self.abfn(a_ab,  a_b)
```

However I want to write it such that I can define a depth and repeatedly split to that depth.
The one caveat is I do *not* want to use recursive functions

How can I iterate in this manner?

I'm using python but the language doesn't really matter.

Comment: What is the data structure you use for your graph?

Comment: @trincot I'm using an api that has basic cartesian -- vertex is just (x,y). Basically just python lists of  tuples. Does that answer your question?

Comment: x is ordered left to right and y is ordered down to up

Comment: So nodes are identified by numbers (are x and y numbers?)

Comment: yeah just x,y tuples

Comment: So how should this algorithm determine the x,y coordinates of any newly created vertex? And how do you structure the edges? Are edges also tuples?

Comment: the new nodes are dependent on the two input nodes ie a_b on a and b. This is shown as lines on the image and in the function calls in the code snippet

Comment: I don't understand. Let's say that vertex a is (13, 20) and vertex b is (6, 7). What should a_b then be? And how do you encode in your data structure that vertex a and vertex b have a connecting edge?

Comment: It's not a shape I just drew that to show the dependency relation

Comment: as mentioned at the top -- the new nodes are the midpoints between the two input nodes. The center point of the line formed between two inputs.

Comment: geometrically, all of the nodes occur on the same line

Comment: Ok, the image made me wondering how they could be colinear.

Comment: yeah I guess the image is a little misleading I could fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code:

```
def midpoint(a, b):
    return ((a[0] + b[0]) / 2, (a[1] + b[1]) / 2)

def abfn(a, b, depth):
    vertices = [a, b]
    for _ in range(depth):
        nextlevel = vertices[:1]
        for a, b in zip(vertices, vertices[1:]):  # all consecutive pairs
            mid = midpoint(a, b)
            nextlevel.extend((mid, b))
        vertices = nextlevel
    return vertices
```

Example call:

```
a = (0, 100)
b = (0, 200)
vertices = abfn(a, b, 2)

print(vertices)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 100), (0.0, 125.0), (0.0, 150.0), (0.0, 175.0), (0, 200)]
```

Comment: I had heard recursive calling is slower and its super difficult to debug but was stumped on how to loop it right.

Comment: A recursive implementation would in this case not be so much slower (if at all), but as the recursion would be nothing else than what is called "tail recursion", an iterative approach is not really far-fetched here. It is another story when you have a recursive algorithm that makes two (or more) recursive calls at each stage of recursion. In that case an iterative equivalent will need to use an explicit stack to actually mimic the recursive approach.

Comment: Looking at this now, I wonder, since each point along the line is just a division of the vector... could this have been done with simply vector math and no recursion?

Comment: Well the `midpoint` function is what I would call vector math, so maybe you ask whether it could have been done without recursion? Yes it can. You get 2^depth number of equally sized segments, so you can do this iteratively as well.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to offset the midpoint by a particular value, would that work as expected with this algorithm? I tried using the section formula described here https://tutorialspoint.dev/algorithm/geometric-algorithms/section-formula-point-divides-line-given-ratio but am getting unexpected results. Not sure if its a math problem or an api thing

Comment: I could put this into another question if you like

Comment: Sure. If you have a problem with implementing that, ask a new question. Provide the code you tried with and how the result differs from expectations.